# Список справа от заголовка CSS

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Как сделать чтобы список был сразу справа от заголовка , а не под ним ?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h5><b>Заголовок</b></h5>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>1</li>
  /
  <li>2</li>
  /
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h5 class="header">
        <b>Заголовок</b>
    </h5>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>1</li>
              /
        <li>2</li>
              /
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.list {
    margin-top: 17px;
    padding: 4px
    float: left;
}

    ul.list li {
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 5px;
        padding: 13px;
    }

.header {
    float: left;
}
```

Результат: https://jsfiddle.net/069v7j3q/

Comment: Wow ! Здорово , даже с комментарием для каждого свойства , спасибо !